# Enable c++ code completion for Eclipse Che

Tags: c++, code-completion, eclipse-che

Is there an option or a plugin to enable C++ code completion for Eclipse Che?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please edit your question with the results of your internet search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Che supports the Language Server Protocol which means that any compatible language server can be added to Che and it will adopt all the language assist features the language server exposes. There is a community effort underway (and nearing completion I believe) to create an open language server for clangd. So it is coming soon to Che.